# How to debug OCX file called from C++ exe from C#?

Tags: c#, c++, ocx

I have an C# app that call executable file written in C++, and this app is using an OCX (COM) project.

Problem is, I cannot debug this DLL file. I can debug the C++ part of app by attach debuger to the process, but no matter what I've tried, I cannot debug this DLL part.

I'm using VS2015. For all projects the PDB files are there, the debugger is set to mixed.

Does anybody have an idea what to do more?

Thanks for any advice

Comment: You need to add code to your question. Show how you are calling the C++ code and if possible show how the C++ code is calling the OCX.

Comment: You probably have ocx source code if you try to debug it? If yes, you can try to add `DebugBreak` function call to this library to activate breakpoint automatically in interesting place.

Comment: Hi, I cannot provide a source coude.

The DebugBreak is OK, only that compiling takes about 6-8 minutes, so changing and trzing gets a lot amout of time. But I will try it, thanks for a hint.

Comment: We are not asking you to provide the source code, we are asking you to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the problem.

Comment: Hi, thank you. With the debug break and some "try and check", I was able to find out, that wrong OCX file has been used for the app. So the PDB has never been loaded.